# python: monitor updates in /proc/mydev file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, python-watchdog

I wrote a kernel module that writes in `/proc/mydev` to notify the python program in userspace. I want to trigger a function in the python program whenever there is an update of data in `/proc/mydev` from the kernel module. What is the best way to listen for an update here? I am thinking about using "watchdog" (https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/). Is there a better way for this?

Comment: That said, tools like watchdog that use inotify or similar will not work with block or character devices. Unless you write your driver to provide a triggering or streaming mechanism, your client needs to poll -- and frankly, polling logic is so innately simple that it's hard to see what question there is that needs to be answered about it.

Comment: Yes! I am doing polling currently. But I was looking for a more efficient way, where my userspace script does not have to keep polling every second.

Comment: You can notify the process whenever a change is made using a conditional variable (or more recommended - event handler)

Comment: If you want a more efficient way, your driver needs to be written to support that more efficient way. The details of how to do that, or even _whether you can_ do that depend on the hardware the driver is interfacing with -- does the hardware itself support some kind of trigger / callback / interrupt mechanism, or does _it_ need to be polled?

Comment: Mind, if you want a kernelspace poll that sends a trigger to userspace when things change, that's certainly possible, but that's not a Python question, it's a Linux kernel module development question. Start with providing a mechanism in your driver; only after you've done that is it time to figure out how to use that mechanism from userspace.

Comment: One approach to consider is making your device have reads block -- when there's a change, write a line to output; when nothing has changed, do nothing -- if you don't send an end-of-file, readers don't need to start reading from the beginning but can just continuously be doing a blocking read to get the next thing as it becomes available. But that's a change to your kernel driver, not your Python program. As I said before, _this isn't a Python question, it's a kernel development question_.

Comment: I setup something similar (I was using watchdog to automatically trigger pytest coverage reports on change) I had jest make a post request to a simple flask API I setup which also had a websocket server running so watchdog triggered the test, jest posted that it was complete and the websocket caused my browser (displaying the html test report) to refresh.

For you, you could likely use an existing bus in place of the websocket server which triggers the 'fetch' instead of polling

Comment: Any idea about my answer? Is it what you are looking for @tarun14110?

Comment: Blocking reads, as suggested by @CharlesDuffy are a good idea, but it will work for /proc files because the content is generated on the fly as it is being read. It can be done using a character special device.

Comment: Yup, a character special is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy and efficient way:

```py
import os
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def myfuction(_time):
    print("file modified, time: "+datetime.fromtimestamp(_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _time = 0
    while True:
        last_modified_time = os.stat("/proc/mydev").st_mtime
        if last_modified_time > _time:
            myfuction(last_modified_time)
            _time = last_modified_time
        sleep(1) # prevent high cpu usage
```

result:

```
file modified, time: 11:44:09
file modified, time: 11:46:15
file modified, time: 11:46:24
```

The `while loop` guarantees that the program keeps listening to changes forever.
You can set the interval by changing the sleep time. Low sleep time causes high CPU usage.

Comment: Procfs entries don't have meaningful mtimes unless the author of the kernel driver went out of their way to make it so. (Also, polling the mtime is still polling -- you get a userspace/kernelspace context switch -- so unlike a real filesystem where checking the mtime is going to be much more efficient than reading contents, it's a much smaller gain here).

Comment: ...which is to say, this _really is just polling with a `sleep()`_, which is what the OP already had before asking this question in the first place.

Comment: (and whether the driver _can_ reasonably set an mtime at all without needing to do something awful like run an ongoing kernel thread that does it's own polling is an additional question that needs to be answered before suitability of this approach can be considered)

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about kernel and drivers. But I enjoyed reading your detailed comments. And I can understand what you mean! However, I tested it with `/proc/cpuinfo` and its mtime was real-time.

Comment: Also, there's not much difference between the efficiency of doing polling in python, or adding the support of triggering userspace to the kernel. It just drains your time and energy.

Comment: So my answer is only a pure python polling script, as a replacement for polling libraries.

Comment: Yes, the cpuinfo mtime is always current, but (like other procfs entries that don't override mtime calculation) it's **always** current even if nothing changed, which means you can't use it to determine when the file needs to be reread.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import os

# get the file descriptor for the proc file
fd = os.open("/proc/mydev", os.O_RDONLY)

# create a polling object to monitor the file for updates
poller = select.poll()
poller.register(fd, select.POLLIN)

# create a loop to monitor the file for updates
while True:
    events = poller.poll(10000)
    if len(events) > 0:
        # read the contents of the file if updated
        print(os.read(fd, 1024))
```

Comment: Did you test whether this actually works with procfs? (Hint: it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install inotify
```

**Example
Code for monitoring a simple, flat path (see “Recursive Watching” for watching a hierarchical structure):**

```
import inotify.adapters

def _main():
    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

    i.add_watch('/tmp')

    with open('/tmp/test_file', 'w'):
        pass

    for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
        (_, type_names, path, filename) = event

        print("PATH=[{}] FILENAME=[{}] EVENT_TYPES={}".format(
              path, filename, type_names))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Expected output:

```
PATH=[/tmp] FILENAME=[test_file] EVENT_TYPES=['IN_MODIFY']
PATH=[/tmp] FILENAME=[test_file] EVENT_TYPES=['IN_OPEN']
PATH=[/tmp] FILENAME=[test_file] EVENT_TYPES=['IN_CLOSE_WRITE']
```

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking about procfs. inotify does not work for procfs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for your situation, since it seems that you're wanting to watch a folder, but this program watches a file at a time until the `main()` loop repeats:

```
import os
import time
def main():
    contents = os.listdir("/proc/mydev")
    for file in contents:
        f = open("/proc/mydev/" + file, "r")
        init = f.read()
        f.close()
        while different = false:
            f = open("/proc/mydev/" + file, "r")
            check = f.read()
            f.close()
            if init !== check:
                different = true
            else:
                different = false
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
        # Write what you would want to happen if a change occured here...
        main()
    main()
main()
```

You could then write what you would want to happen right before the last usage of `main()`, as it would then repeat.
Also, this may contain errors, since I rushed this.
Hope this at least helps!

Comment: This is a polling approach, which the OP already knows how to do. Their question is about whether something more efficient is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do this efficiently without modifying your kernel driver.**

Instead of using procfs, have it register a new character device under `/dev`, and write that driver to make new content available to read from that device only when new content has in fact come in from the underlying hardware, such that the application layer can issue a blocking read and have it return only when new content exists.

A good example to work from (which also has plenty of native Python clients) is the evdev devices in the input core.